# How to add button click alert droppable and sortabel but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a problem in adding a button in jquery ui sortable as an example in the following url: 
http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

I want to add a button when the button is pressed it will display the alert, the problem is when the button is pressed the alert does not appear

```
$( "<li><button onclick='saya()'>Berhasil</button></li>" ).appendTo("#cart ol");
```

I added a function to pop up alerts

```
function saya(){ alert("hello world");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set an `onclick` attribute directly in the html. Attach a click event instead :

```
$( '<li><button>Berhasil</button></li>').click(saya).appendTo("#cart ol");
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c22d4e15/)